# Filter nested list with list comprehension based on other list in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have two lists like this:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[7,8,9]]
b = [1,2]
```

I would now like to filter list a, to keep only the items which contain the items in list b. So the desired output would look like this:

```
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
```

I have tried some nested list comprehensions, which I could think of, but could not get the desired output. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried already?

Comment: some things, but I was just messing around here. I find it hard to wrap my head around this: `[i for i in a if i in b in i]` `[i for i in a if i in i in b]` `[[i for i in a if i in b] for ele in a]` `[[i for i in b] for i in a]` None of these produced the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this :

```
print([i for i in a if any(map(i.__contains__,b))])

>>> [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Also personally I find the use of `map` with `__contains__` quite confusing. I would simply write `any(x in i for x in b)` (it's even one character shorter ^_^)

Comment: Good point, +1 , i just forgot to update it ... :)

Answer (score 1):

A combination of list comprehension and sets would yield the wanted result. Note; I assume that repeated items and ordering is not of interest, if this is the case - a set won't work since it ignores ordering and only allows unique items.

A simple list comprehension would do, like below

```py
filter_items = set(filter_items)
[sublist for sublist in original_list if not set(sublist).isdisjoint(filter_items)]
```

There's mainly one interesting part of this list comprehension, namely the `if not set(sublist).isdisjoint(filter_items)`. Here you only keep the sublist if the set of sublist is not [disjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets) of the set filter_items i.e. none of the filter_items is in the sublist.

for your given example the provided answer would yield the following:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[7,8,9]]
>>> b = set([1,2])
>>> [sublist for sublist in a if not set(sublist).isdisjoint(b)]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Why not just `set(sublist).intersection(b)`? If the intersection is not empty then you want to keep the list... (set methods doesn't require a set as an argument)

Comment: You can make `b` a set before comprehension to avoid repeated construction and use `b.isdisjoint(sublist)` (`isdisjoint` accepts any iterable, AFAIR).

Comment: @tomerikoo because it is unnecessary work, you don't really need intersection - you want only to know whether this intersection is not empty. `isdisjoint` is more optimal here.

Comment: @SUTerliakov From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint): *"Return True if the set has no elements in common with other. __Sets are disjoint if and only if their intersection is the empty set__."* I doubt there's a (*critical*) difference in runtime...

Comment: @tomerikoo Interesting, I'll measure when I have time. However, I suppose that `isdisjoint` performs short-circuit evaluation similar to `any` and will return `False` after first matching item, while `intersection` will check whole set anyway. It's like `any(iterator)` that won't exhaust iterator and will stop after first `True`. I really doubt that `isdisjoint` is implemented like `not bool(intersection)`, it's inefficient.

Comment: @SUTerliakov It would make a lot of sense if it ***wasn't*** implemented that way indeed... Would be interesting to see hard numbers. Do ping me if you get around to testing it :)

Comment: Yes, [it does](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2e8f721c0f275d9d7c018b4a2a66f053cf34bb36/Objects/setobject.c#L1344). So if `b` is large (say, 10k items), `isdisjoint` can be **much** faster. But I'll compare and notify you:)

Comment: @SUTerliakov Well, I couldn't wait... I created [this repl](https://replit.com/@TomerKalish/disjoint-vs-intersection#main.py) and the summary of the results are (as I suspected): the less disjoint the sets are (i.e. more elements in common) the faster `isdisjoint` is comparing with `intersection`. For fully disjoint sets they basically behave the same...

Comment: So all in all I stand corrected! @Gabriel your initial hunch was better than mine. `isdisjoint` seems to be a better fit in this case ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[7,8,9]]
b = [1,2]

result = [lst for lst in a if any(x in lst for x in b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `set` approach the `in` can be mimic with an intersection:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[7,8,9]]
b = [1,2]

b_as_set = set(b)

out = [l for l in a if b_as_set.intersection(l)]
# [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this.

```
a = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[7,8,9]]
b = [1,2]

print([lst for lst in a if any([item in b for item in lst])])
```

Comment: No need to create a list inside the `any` call